# Edit my text file content in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a one file `"xyz.text.erb"` in my `view` folder. I want to edit that content. Like I am an admin and I want to edit that `xyz.text.erb` file content in an editor when I click on save then change content of `xyz.text.erb` file. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered putting that content into a database instead of the file system?

Comment: using database that i know but i want this via file system because this file in my mailer. and i use that file for sending emails so that i want to edit this content via admin

Comment: Agree with mu is too short. Needs to be in db otherwise it won't get loaded. You also need to rephrase your question so it's clearer what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because if you change the content of the file after start server rails, rails doesn't reload the file so you must put your content in a database.

Rails in development reload all files each time but in production you can remove all folder app the application continue without any problems.